# Edit Text Hint is not visible in android studio design preview but is visible on emulator when app runs

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext

Hint is not visible in android studio design preview but when I run the app on emulator or my mobile device then hint is shown in the edit text. How to make the hint visible in design preview also.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is usually the case with edittext.
Change the background of the edittext to white and it should display in the layout editor too.
If it doesn't, check the hint text colour.

Comment: yeah just by clicking on background attribute the hint appears and without even selecting any color

Comment: but after selecting the background color the blue line below edit text disappears .I then try to make the background of edit text transparent but then also blue line is not showing. How to fix this?

Comment: The blue line comes when the edittext is on focus. That means when the user taps it, the blue line appears. When he exits the edittext, it returns back to normal. That's Android's default style.

Comment: I mean that the line is not showing any more below the edit text and not the blue line . Yeah in above comment i should not have written blue .

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your project. Go to File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart.

Comment: it doesn't fix my problem nothing changes after applying your solution

Answer (score 0):

i think you should try to resize the layout in design part or go file and do invalidate caches and restart option